# Conflict appleaccountd with MAMP mySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp

This morning, I turned on my Macbook to work (Sonoma 14.2.1), turned on MAMP and... the light became orange. So I did some tests, Apache is working so as PHP, but not mySQL. I did take a look in the log and it seems to have a problem (error) "Another process with pid 1970 is using unix socket file" (at the bottom of the log I did copy). This pid is listed in Activity Monitor as process "appleaccountd". Googling a bit, it seems this process is related to iCloud, Apple ID or something, I don't know.

How can I fix this?

The mysql_error log:

```
2024-01-15T14:25:46.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2024-01-15T14:25:46.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57
2024-01-15T14:25:46.860823Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2024-01-15T14:25:46.862149Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2024-01-15T14:25:46.862263Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.39) starting as process 15182 ...
2024-01-15T14:25:46.877605Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2024-01-15T14:25:46.880577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-01-15T14:25:46.880629Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-01-15T14:25:46.880667Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2024-01-15T14:25:46.880701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-15T14:25:46.881468Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-01-15T14:25:46.881760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2024-01-15T14:25:46.885433Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-01-15T14:25:46.916650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-15T14:25:46.941850Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.025712Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-01-15T14:25:47.025947Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-15T14:25:47.056727Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.058108Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.058167Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.058638Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-01-15T14:25:47.109019Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.39 started; log sequence number 5570382
2024-01-15T14:25:47.109395Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.109806Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-15T14:25:47.120190Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2024-01-15T14:25:47.120353Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2024-01-15T14:25:47.131917Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.131980Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.132008Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.132021Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.134249Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.134436Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.135239Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2024-01-15T14:25:47.137383Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.137484Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2024-01-15T14:25:47.138463Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.139289Z 0 [ERROR] Another process with pid 1970 is using unix socket file.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.139341Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2024-01-15T14:25:47.139369Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: After an OS restart, the problem vanished. This time I have waited a long time before trying to turn on MAMP, this might avoid conflicts since everything else is already loaded - my guess. I don't know if I leave this question open, is not really answered, you tell me...